# Is it possible to set an environment variable in PHP and redirect via .htaccess based on that environment variable?

Tags: php, .htaccess, environment-variables

I have a **protected** folder. I want people who are logged in (via PHP / WordPress) to have access to the folder and the files therein.

Those who are not logged in should be redirected via **.htaccess**.

Can the **.htaccess** rewrite condition be based off an environment variable or a server variable which I added *or edited* from PHP?

**UPDATE:**

See my answer below.

Comment: PHP has the ability to redirect .. why don't you just use that?

Comment: Changed the question to better address my particular problem. Does that help @tandu?

Comment: @tandu I can't redirect using PHP because not all files would be PHP. I also don't want to redirect all requests to a PHP file and fopen the files becuase there are some quite large files that need to be protected.

Comment: Update. I think this can be done with cookies. PHP can write to the cookie. **.htaccess** can mod_rewrite based off the cookie variable. Can't wait to try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I solved it.

My folder system is setup like this:

```
/file-share/users-folder-name
```

My `.htaccess` file under `/file-share` is as follows:

```
# .htaccess /file-share

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# no cookie set    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*client.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /file-share-redirect.php?q=$1 [NC,L]

# cookie set 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !verified$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} client=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /file-share/%1/$1?verified [NC,L,QSA]

# custom 404
ErrorDocument 404 /file-share-redirect.php?e=404&q=$1

#end
```

If the cookie is set and the file exists in the client's folder then the client is redirected seamlessly to the requested file. The final file request is also given a url parameter to avoid a loop in redirection.

If a user is logged but the cookie is not set I have my `file-share-redirect.php` file create the cookie then redirect to the requested file. The cookie created in the code below is set to expire in an hour.

```
<?php setcookie('client', $users_folder_name, time()+3600); ?>
```

**UPDATE**

You can keep the cookie secure by using an encrypted cookie name and value. The cookie will only be created on systems where users log in.

PHP's [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) will even let you create a cookie that is **inaccessible from JavaScript**. *I double checked this.*

The subfolder names will be quite complex, completely unguessable. No one will ever see the subfolder names except those with ftp access. Even those logged in will only see `/_/filename.ext`, without the subfolder.

Comment: Nobody can be helped by this but spoiled. As this does no protection at all

Comment: Why does this offer no protection at all? Explain please.

Comment: anyone can fake a cookie and enter anyone's else  "private" area.

Comment: Edited the answer to add more security. This is my solution. @YourCommonSense Thanks for your criticisms. Any solutions or just complaints?

Comment: Really happy with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess (hypertext access) file is a directory-level configuration file supported by several web servers. I can't think of any simple way of how you could access runtime variables set in PHP with .htaccess as .htaccess allows no "execution" of commands, it is just a bunch of config directives.

You could maybe do some sort of VERY VERY strange combination of .htaccess and CGI scripts and maybe more to access a webservice @ PHP level, but that would be far beyond my programming skills and I suppose beyond those of most PHP developers too...

At least this is what I can tell you, I would be interestd too if someone knows a hack for this...

The easiest way of how to do such redirects would in my opinion be `header("Location: xxx.html");` directly in PHP.

Comment: I think this can be done with http cookies. PHP can write to the cookie. **.htaccess** can mod_rewrite based off the cookie variable. _Can't wait to try this._

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the `.htaccess` file on the fly using PHP to set these variables.  I mean, you can, but the `.htaccess` file is used by the entire server, not per-user.  Unless you wanted to do some ridiculous write-username-environment-variables to `.htaccess` and hope it works somehow, you're much better off just doing this via php.  If they're not logged in, you can redirect them away with PHP so they won't be able to see the protected folders either.

If you want to keep them out of an entire folder but you don't want to do something like `require security-check.php` on every file, you could look into using `auto_prepend_file`.  You could also use your `.htaccess` to route all file access through one specific php file that does this.  You would need to do this if you were keeping people out of non-php files.